# Change image on success jqPuzzle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jqPuzzle JS library found [here](http://www.2meter3.de/jqPuzzle/#o3) and I am trying to change the source image when the user completes the puzzle.

The library states that it has objects which in them you can define functions on what to do when success.

This is how I integrate the HTML for the puzzle to work :

```
<img src="myImg1.jpg" alt="First puzzle image" class="jqPuzzle" />
```

The Documentation then says that below is the object to use when defining what to do on success:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // define your own settings 
        var mySettings = { 
            success: { 
                callback: function(results) {  
                    alert('Gelöst in ' + results.moves + ' Zügen und ' + 
                        + results.seconds + ' Sekunden.'); 
                } 
        }; 
        }); 
</script>
```

Could you guys kindly assist me in how to write such function to change the source image when the user successfully completes the first image ?

Comment: are you passing the `mySettings` object into the jqPuzzle object?

Answer (score 0):

Try passsing the `mySettings` object into the jqPuzzle object

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // define your own settings 
    var mySettings = { 
        success: { 
            callback: function(results) {  
                alert('Gelöst in ' + results.moves + ' Zügen und ' + 
                    + results.seconds + ' Sekunden.'); 
            } 
    }; 

    // once you've got your settings initialised
    // you must pass them into jqPuzzle
    $('.jqPuzzle').jqPuzzle(mySettings);
})
```

**--EDIT--**

If you're trying to update the image inside the success function, can you just change the `SRC` property of the image?

```
function(results) {  
    alert('Gelöst in ' + results.moves + ' Zügen und ' + 
                    + results.seconds + ' Sekunden.'); 

    // this line can be improved by giving your img element an ID property
    var img = document.getElementsByClassName('jqPuzzle')[0];
    img.src = 'myImg2.jpg';
}
```

Comment: it's not about the mSettings not working, it's about what function should I write to replace the original image once the user successfully completes the first puzzle

Comment: I implemented your solution, however when completing the puzzle it is still not changing the image. It is still getting the original image